# Calculating cold temp on mixing valve

Tags: percentages, ratio, mixing

I need a formula to calculate the cold temperature on a mixing valve system when given the hot temp, mixing percentage, and mixed temp. I can determine the hot and mixed temps with temp probes, but the cold temp has to be calculated.
[image: Mixing Valve Diagram]

Comment: Are you sure that the second mixed water temperature is 60? If you add just a little cold water, the temperature should decrease just a little, unless the cold water is well below freezing

Comment: Are temps are hypothetical, but all temps listed are possible to occur during operation. Right now I'm just looking for a mathematical formula to determine the cold water temp with the given variables.

Answer (score 0):

Use conservation of energy. Energy given by a quantity $m_H$ of hot water while cooling is proportional to $(T_H-T_M)\cdot m_H$, while the energy absorbed bu the cold water is $(T_M-T_C)\cdot m_C$.
Then $$(T_H-T_M)\cdot m_H=(T_M-T_C)\cdot m_C\\T_C=T_M-(T_H-T_M)\frac{m_H}{m_C}$$

Comment: If possible I would like a formula where I could just plug in the variables to get my value. I'm not exactly a mathematician, more of a tradesman.

Comment: I've added the last step. You can use the ratio of percentages instead of ratio of  masses.